# Displaying Json data on view ( LARAVEL )

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

I am working in laravel project and i want to display my json data from url into the view dashboard.blade, And this is the sample json data:

> {"response":{"result":{"Contacts":{"row":[{"no":"1","fl":[{"val":"CONTACTID","content":"144120000000079041"},{"val":"First
>   Name","content":"Tata"},{"val":"Last
>   Name","content":"Nyerere"},{"val":"Email","content":"nyereredaniel@gmail.com"},{"val":"Account
>   Name","content":"null"},{"val":"Phone","content":"255652400670"},{"val":"Mobile","content":"null"}]},{"no":"2","fl":[{"val":"CONTACTID","content":"144120000000069001"},{"val":"First
>   Name","content":"Daniel"},{"val":"Last
>   Name","content":"Nyerere"},{"val":"Email","content":"nyereredaniel@hotmail.com"},{"val":"Account
>   Name","content":"null"},{"val":"Phone","content":"255754897505"},{"val":"Mobile","content":"null"}]},{"no":"3","fl":[{"val":"CONTACTID","content":"144120000000065068"},{"val":"First
>   Name","content":"Lawrence"},{"val":"Last
>   Name","content":"Zoho"},{"val":"Email","content":"support@zohosupport.com"},{"val":"ACCOUNTID","content":"144120000000065066"},{"val":"Account
>   Name","content":"Zoho"},{"val":"Phone","content":"1 888 900
>   9646"},{"val":"Mobile","content":"null"}]}]}},"uri":"/api/json/contacts/getrecords"}}

And here is my Controller method:

```
 public function getDashboard()
{
    $url      = "MY URL IS HERE";
    $json     = file_get_contents($url);
    $json     = json_decode($json, true);
    $response = $json['response'];
    $result   = $response['result'];
    $contact  = $result['Contacts'];
    $data     = $contact['row'];
    return view('dashboard')->with('posts', $data);
}
```

And here is my dashboard.blade that displays the json data on my view page:

```
       @foreach($posts as $post)
            @foreach($post['fl'] as $row)
                <article class="post">
                    @if($row['val'] == 'First Name')
                       First Name: {{ $row['content'] }}
                    @endif
                </article>
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
```

Can anyone assist me on the issue and how to write the foreach in dashboard.blade file as i want to display the data on my view as:

```
First Name    Last Name     Phone:
Tata          Nyerere       255754897505
```

As for now it only display

```
First Name: Tata
```

Please assist me as i have spent time to solve this
I will appreciate your help guys.
Thanks in advance`

Answer (score 0):

Use `return view('dashboard')->with('leads', $contact);` if you want to iterate `$leads['row']` in the view.

Otherwise, you can just use `return view('dashboard')->with('leads', $data);` and iterate `$leads` in the view this way `@foreach($leads as $rows)`

Comment: I have tried with  `return view('dashboard')->with('leads', $contact);`     with   `$leads['row'] as $rows`      i get the error                   `'Undefined index: First Name (View: C:\wamp\www\ZOHOCRMWIKI\resources\views\dashboard.blade.php)` '

Answer (score 0):

Make a change from this line

`$data = $contact['row'];`

to

`$data = $contact;`

While the second error you have with index `First Name` and other is because your data isn't in those format to be accessible using like that.

Your first foreach will get into those `no` and `fl` index. You better reformat your response data before passing into blade.

[image]

Comment: Still error `Undefined index: First Name (View: C:\wamp\www\ZOHOCRMWIKI\resources\views\dashboard.blade.php)`

Comment: @Nyerere look at the updated answer. You have to code more to get it working.

Comment: Can you assist on how can i reformat the json content above? @cjmling

Comment: Look now: my controller method:-

Answer (score 0):

You may try `json_decode(json_encode($data))`.

If the data came from JsonResource, fields that are not existed in the original model will be omitted. It looks weird when you json_encode `$data`, it works, but not if you want to do something like `$data->first_name`.